# Android Emulator Won't Start - Bad Request

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-12.04, bad-request

I am trying to run an Android emulator in Android Studio. But the emulator window (view) never launches. Instead, it fails with the error:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
X Error of failed request: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
```

I am running Android Studio 24.1.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 on a HP Pavillian dv7 laptop. The `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variables are set correctly.

Is this some sort of graphics card problem? (If so, is it fixable?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some problem with the drivers of  AMD/ATI Catalyst 
try using the info in 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513

Comment: This has been a long rabbit hole of hilarious problems. But you were broadly-speaking right. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.